# Facing an issue with downloading docker images in parallel using ansible

Tags: linux, docker, ansible

1. I need to download all the images in parallel and run it to save download time.
2. I tried creating an Ansible playbook which uses `async` and `poll` to run tasks in background

Playbook

```yaml
- name: Start docker-compose services
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Start service 1
      shell: docker-compose up -d
      async: 300
      poll: 0
      register: service1
      delay: 5
      args:
        chdir: "service1"

    - name: Start service 2
      shell: docker-compose up -d
      async: 300
      poll: 0
      register: service2
      delay: 5
      args:
        chdir: "service2"


    - name: Start service 3
      shell: docker-compose up -d
      async: 300
      poll: 0
      register: service3
      delay: 5
      args:
        chdir: "service3"


    - name: Wait for services to complete
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: result
      until: result.finished
      retries: 30
      delay: 10
      loop:
        - "{{ service1 }}"
        - "{{ service2 }}"
        - "{{ service3 }}"

    - name: Print async task output
      debug:
        var: item.result.stdout_lines
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
```

Is it a correct approach as it's not working as expected

Comment: Now that you have described your requirements, what is your issue? What does not work I your current playbook?

Comment: Its not downloading image in parallel

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: service1 image size is around 500MB, service2 and service3 is around 200MB....It should have download service2 and service 3 in the meantime right but it did not

Comment: What happens if you remove the `delay` keyword from all tasks but the `async_status` one?

Comment: I did try that but it did not help

Comment: Did you run it in verbose mode with -vvvv ? to check the output? If not, please do it nad paste the output.

Comment: `service1 image size is around 500MB, service2 and service3 is around 200MB....It should have download service2 and service 3 in the meantime right but it did not ` <= my guess is that this is what you **think** because of the way the async status is checked but is not the reality. If task1 is the longuest, it will also be fhe first one checked in your loop. So you will wait until that task reports "done" until you move to check the next one. When you do, that task will already be over and will return ok immediately (and the next one too). If I'm wrong, please post a correct [mre].

Comment: An easy way to check my guess is to reorder your `async_status` check in reverse order so that you check the theoretically longest task at the end.

Comment: And to be complete: `It should have download service2 and service 3 in the meantime right but it did not` <= Since we have absolutely no idea of the content of your compose files, the fact it is longer could very well be that those services need to build local images and the other does not, Or you could download your images on different registries with one being much slower than the other... Once more, what is needed is a [mre]